# Conditional using isDevMode is not being tree shaked

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, tree-shaking

My current code is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'some-selector',
})
export class SomeSelectorDirective {
  constructor() {
    if (isDevMode() && someCondition) {
      console.warn('Some warning.');
    }

    // some omitted code
  }
}
```

The problem is that this condition is not being tree shaked when I ran `ng build --prod`, however if I replace `isDevMode()` by `!environment.production` the code is stripped out. I want to know a reason for this: why isn't code wrapped by `isDevMode` being dropped on a build prod?

---

Note that I'm using Angular 10.x.y.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the optimizer (Terser.js) doesn't apply the function in order to check it runtime value.

When you are using the inline version, webpack's `DefinePlugin` will replace the inline to the value itself, therefore before optimization it will look like:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'some-selector',
})
export class SomeSelectorDirective {
  constructor() {
    if (false && someCondition) {
    // ---^ inlined the false value
      console.warn('Some warning.');
    }

    // some omitted code
  }
}
```

with this code, the optimizer can remove the if for sure, because it is a "dead" branch.